# python login form vulnerability?

Tags: web-development, python, security, web

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Login Page</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<FORM method="POST" action="http://yourserver/cgi-bin/login.py">
<paragraph> Enter your login name: <input type="text" name="login">
<paragraph> Enter your password: <input type=password name="password">
<paragraph> <input type="submit" value="Connect">
</FORM>
</CENTER>
<HR>

</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

login.py:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi

def header(title):
   print "Content-type: text/html\n"
   print "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>%s</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n" % (title)

def footer():
   print "</BODY></HTML>"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
password = "python"

if not form:
   header("Login Response")
elif form.has_key("login") and form["login"].value != "" and form.has_key("password")       and form["password"].value == password:
header("Connected ..." )
   print "<center><hr><H3>Welcome back," , form["login"].value, ".</H3><hr></center>"
   print r"""<form><input type="hidden" name="session" value="%s"></form>""" % (form["login"].value)
   print "<H3><a href=browse.html>Click here to start browsing</a></H3>"

else:
   header("No success!")
   print "<H3>Please go back and enter a valid login.</H3>"

footer()
```

I would like to make this login form vulnerable to RCE (remote code execution), is this possible with the function `eval()` or `exec()`.

I am looking for functions that introduce a vulnerability within the login form. Are there whole classes/modules that contain dangerous functionally? Also would it be possible to make this login form vulnerable to remote code execution?

Comment: Are you going to use this knowledge for good or for evil?

Comment: This is for a hacking challenge i am creating :) so its for good :D (whitehat)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to make this login form vulnerable to RCE ( remote code execution), is this possible with the function eval() or exec()?

Yes. If you pass unchecked user input to either of those functions then you are allowing remote code execution.

> I am looking for functions that introduce a vulnerability within the login form.I am particularly interested in Remote Code Execution vulnerabilities. Are there whole classes/modules that contain dangerous functionally?

Yes. Python can open files/delete files/connect to databases/etc. So yes there is plenty of bad things that could happen if you can execute arbitrary code.

> Also would it be possible to make this login form vulnerable to remote code execution?

Yes. See above.