# Is it possible to combine programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I've been programming for a while, I've written some rudimentary programs, and I want to keep learning. I've reached that point where you just don't know what to learn next, and I'd like to ask a question for my own curiosity.

The question, in a nutshell, is if you can combine multiple programming languages into 1 result? For example, can this code be possible?

```
<html>
cout << "Hello world!";
</html>
```

or

```
import java.util.Scanner;
cout << "Insert a number from 1 to 10";
Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("The value you entered was" +n.newLine());
```

This feels like a silly question but I can't possible know if it's possible or not, so that's why I'm asking it. In [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137129/python-login-form-vulnerability) question I notice he is using Python code in html code, if my above example is not possible, what did he do?

Comment: For this to work (without making people insane), one needs *at least* strict rules regarding how they interact and which parts should be processed as which language.

Comment: There are a few languages which are very frequently embedded into other languages (e.g., [lua](http://www.lua.org/) ).

Comment: It would take one hellova lexer/parser.

Comment: @Brian Lua is embedded in that the interpreter is linked into some C or C++ code and used to run Lua code stored in strings or external files, possibly exposing C/C++ objects to the Lua code. Lua is *not* (not frequently, if at all) "embedded" in the sense of this question.

Comment: There was a post I saw a few weeks ago where someone wrote a program that compiled - without edit - in four different languages (C, brainfuck, whitespace, and something else...).  I think it was the code-golf site, but now I can't find it.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://www.chrisseaton.com/katahdin/

Comment: @Brian, that's a different kind of embedding. SQL would make a better example (especially if it's something like Oracle `Pro*` stuff).

Comment: That's like making five alphabets each with different symbols for the 26 letters and intermixing them in a single book: pointless, irritating and redundant.

Comment: @ThomasX, have you ever read "War and Peace" (L. Tolstoy)? It's written in two languages originally, with two different alphabets.

Comment: I think people are clearly forgetting the most common (and only valid real-life that I can think of) use case of "combining languages" -- **ASM fragments in C/C++ programs**, usually for performance reasons.

Comment: @TC1, why is it the "only valid"? There are thousands of perfectly valid cases for mixing languages. And nowadays asm in C is not for performance reasons, but rather interoperability or simply things that cannot be expressed in C (e.g., trampolines).

Comment: +1, I always wondered how this can be done .. will you be happy knowing that we can call code of another language from one language.(Eg: the java runtime class). This can help you combining different languages to solve one single problem.  you can use the strengths of different languages to attack particular parts of the problem best solved with some particular technology

Comment: Little late to your party but check this out; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201894/embedding-programming-languages-into-other-languages?noredirect=1#comment393604_201894

Comment: @ThomasX: But it isn't written in two languages where the same symbols are used but mean a different thing. That's a whole different ballgame. And while it might even be entertaining for a book (and even setting up a plot twist), compilers are not known for their love of prose, the plot twist or reader misdirection.

Comment: This is actually pretty common in the mainframe world. Unisys has a rudimentary script language (ECL) that was "enhanced" over time with editing- and flow control, not by adding statements to the language but by supporting the embedding of other language blocks and directives in the code that trigger the execution of other interpreters. And some people try to write a static converter for that. There is nothing desirable about these systems, no one in his right mind would design something like this. These systems are this way for historical reasons. Bolted-on kludges to fulfil some need.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You first example is sort of possible. Usually such things happen in PHP (and other related web-programming languages) like this:

```
<HTML>
<?PHP
call_some_php_function(1,2,"a","b"); /* This is may return nothing, a text string, or actual HTML markup code */
?>
</HTML>
```

Some important points to note about this example:

- HTML is NOT a progamming language, it is a markup language.
- The PHP and HTML and not executed/interpreted in the same place: PHP code is executed by a PHP interpreter running on the server and the result is "injected" into the surrounding HTML. Then that whole blob is sent to the client/browser which renders the complete HTML.

Your second example looks like some sort of mash-up of C++ and Java. It's possible to have compiled modules written in different languages talk to each other, but to combine Java and C++ in the same source file would be extremely confusing and difficult: how would the compiler know which statements are Java and which are C++?

I suppose in theory you could write a special compiler/pre-processor with "language" indicators such as:

```
Java
{
    import java.util.Scanner;
}
C++
{
   cout << "Insert a number from 1 to 10";
}
Java
{
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in); //Actually, this line *could* be a C++ line - it's hard for me to tell just by looking at it.
    System.out.println("The value you entered was" +n.newLine());
}
```

But I'm honestly not sure you'd gain anything useful by doing this.

Also, how would this hybrid language environment handle language features which are incompatible between the two?

Comment: An example everyone forgot about (including myself), so please feel free to add it to your answer: `CUDA`. It's a mixture of two very different C languages, with some functions compiled for a device (GPU), and some remaining on a host, with communication layer being inferred.

Comment: It's not uncommon to have JavaScript as well as HTML and PHP on one page. Horrible, but not uncommon.

Comment: Not so familiar with PHP, but ASP.NET (whether C# or VB.NET) code generates HTML and JavaScript - and the JavaScript is often embedded right there in the .aspx page. Total separation is often quoted as an ideal, but a quick overview of the questions on SO tagged ASP.NET will give you an idea of how complex that can be.

Comment: @sq33G - ASP.NET generates HTML code.  You can include javascript if you want.  ASP.NET certainly  is NOT what the author describes as wanting to do.

Comment: I was going to bring up PHP/HTML/JS in one document if no one else had.

Answer (score 19):

## Short Answer

Not really.

---

## Long Answer

### Embedding

Generally, a single source file contains code for exactly one programming language.  It is uncommon for multiple languages to be combined in a single file for a couple of reasons:

- **Parsing** several syntactically-different languages at once is extremely difficult (if not outright impossible).
- Different languages **treat programming differently**.  Haskell's notion of a function is different than C++'s.

### Linking

Different programming languages that share a common [application binary interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) may be combined to form a single executable or library.  Getting the two languages' signatures available inside each other often takes a bit of work, but [tools exist](http://www.swig.org/) to ease the process.

### Polyglots

[Polyglot code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29) is valid and equivalent in more than one language.  [Stack Overflow's 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/404) features one such program:

[image: Stack Overflow 404 polyglot]

[This prints "404"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28647/153179) in Python, Perl, Ruby, C, Brainfuck and Befunge.

### Conclusion

Languages are rarely mixed within files, and when they are, [it is for laughs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).  People even try to avoid mixing languages within projects because of the extra hassle it introduces.  So, while it can be technically possible, mixing different languages is neither common nor pragmatic.

Comment: I see no Ruby here...

Comment: @JasonLewis I do not know Ruby, but [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code/28647#28647) post says that it evaluates line #4.

Comment: Well... the interpreter can handle it... but if you try it in `irb` (Ruby REPL) it chokes. if you do `ruby -e 'print(202*2);exit();'` it will evaluate and return 404... but it's not only not idiomatic Ruby, it's something no Ruby programmer would **ever** write. That's why I said I saw no Ruby. Not that it won't execute; it works, but only by accident.

Comment: Languages aren't always mixed for laughs. Most C compilers allow you to mix Assembly and C, and so do many Forths. Back in the Eighties, one of the best BASIC dialects in the game, Acorn's BBC Basic, allowed you to mix 6502 assembly and that was a very desirable feature then. It certainly made BBC users laugh, but pretty much everyone else cried, especially the ones who had to assemble 6502 machine code by hand and stick raw opcodes in their programs in `DATA` statements. Not that I'm bitter or anything. Noooo.

Comment: Are you sure that SQL in Oracle Pro*C or Pro*Fortran is just for laughs? Or LINQ in C#. Well, it's fun and funny, but some people are kinda serious about it any way.

Comment: @SK-logic SQL is a Structured Query Language, not a programming language.

Comment: One of the sad things about modern software development is that multiple language apps are so much harder now.  Back in the DOS days, nearly everything compiled to the same object file and used the same parameter passing conventions.  It was real easy to just link them together.  Nowadays, not so much...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible indeed. Not the way you've imagined that, of course. There are some [languages](http://www.chrisseaton.com/katahdin/) out there built specifically for this purpose.

In practice, it might be very useful to mix a number of [domain-specific languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) into a single host language. There's rarely a need in mixing two or more equally "general purpose" languages together in single source code file, although you'll often find projects written in both, say, VB.NET and C#, with different language components compiled separately.

As for HTML, it's just a markup language. You may often find a server-side code (e.g., in VB.NET), HTML markup and client-side Javascript code mixed into a single source file, although it is considered a bad practice by many.

Answer (score 7):

This is often called [polyglot code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29) - there are some fun/insane examples if you follow the link or in various other places on the web. Most of these are just for fun / to prove it is possible.

More seriously, there are various real life examples where two or more different languages can be usefully combined:

- **Web templating** - languages such as PHP or JSP files mix code into HTML. Opinions differ widely on whether this is a good idea or not.
- **Macro languages** - often a macro language is mixed into the source file such as C/C++ preprocessor macros. There are also interesting cases like Lisp where the macro language is itself Lisp (the only difference is whether the code is run at compile time or runtime)
- **DSLs** - often a domain specific language is defined to help solve a particular problem effectively, which is embedded into the source code of another language. Here's an example of a [beautiful DSL for SQL](http://sqlkorma.com/) which can be embedded in Clojure code.
- **Scripting** - some dynamic languages are particularly useful for short scripts and are designed to be embedded within software written in another language. [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) scripts for example are very easy to embed within a Java application.
- **Polyglot projects** - sometimes it makes sense to use multiple languages just to exploit the different capabilities of each. For example, the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) supports multiple languages that can interoperate fairly transparently, so you might mix Java (for speed and statically typed OOP) with Clojure (for interactive development, concurrency and functional programming). Such projects still typically separate the different languages into separate source files/folders, but they are compiled at the same time to produce a single application.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do some combination of languages using [Perl Inline](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/Inline/Inline.pod) which allows to write a Perl script and insert sections of code written in a different language:

> Inline has support for C, C++, Java, Python, Ruby, Tcl, Assembler, Basic, Guile, Befunge, Octave, Awk, BC, TT (Template Toolkit), WebChat and even PERL

Comment: I'd never heard of Perl Inline. It's an interesting idea, but does it give any advantage over what is probably the usual approach of having separate modules for non-PERL code?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Inline Perl is a great module, but it has some flaws. It works well, but only to the extent of fairly basic code. Although it has been worked on for a while, I wouldn't use it in any kind of production.

Answer (score 3):

[Embedded SQL](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL) was a common way to embed SQL statements into programs of other languages.

These days it has been replaced almost entirely by easier-to-compile API-based Database access that doesn't need to modify the host language, but use its normal abilities instead.

Comment: These days an embedded SQL made its comeback in form of LINQ, and it is here to stay.

Comment: @SK-logic: how is LINQ anything like embedded SQL? It's not a different language, it's simply the application of additional language constructs in the host language.

Comment: LINQ is a very typical embedded DSL, semantically alien to its host language. And, in case of LINQ2SQL, it behaves exactly the same way as the old embedded SQL did, it is translated literally to SQL.

Comment: But embedded SQL is not "translated to SQL". You write the *literal* SQL inside your C code (and not usually within string constants either). Even 'though LINQ uses language features that were (as far as I know) developed specifically for LINQ it's "just" an API within its host language.

Comment: Pro*C and Pro*Fortran translated SQL statements a bit. And LINQ is not "just" an API, it's an API with syntax sugar and a bunch of interchangeable compiler back-ends. Which makes it a perfect example of a full-blown embedded DSL.

Comment: @SK-logic: as far as I know (and I might be wrong, because I'm not a .NET expert), the "syntactic sugar" that LINQ uses is not restricted to be used in LINQ only, but *could* be used in other libraries. Yes, it *is* an embedded DSL, but the same could be said about some APIs (internal DSLs).

Comment: LINQ syntax sugar is, well, LINQ-specific. There is no point in using it with anything else, only LINQ backends.

Answer (score 2):

Several programming languages can be used to form 1 exe. One way is to use DLLs. Of course there are various concerns about this. For example, parameter compatibility, COM compatibility and such. In fact, if you think of how you call a database system to do you work, you might find that the DBMS is not always written in a language you know. You probably don't even care as long as the interface is known.

This concept is taken further when your solution utilizes Web Services, which is even a cleaner way combine multiple software components.

In the .NET world, all of the above applies, more over, on the interface level XAML and HTML interfaces can live together in Silverlight.

In the UNIX world, at one time, we used KShell scripts to launch C++ and COBOL programs so that the solution could work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be worth mentioning [Cython](http://cython.org/) here. It's a superset of Python for writing C extensions and although it is really a unique language in itself, it pretty much allows you to use C code in Python code, if you conform to Cython's Python style syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can "mix" languages in HTML. It's actually important to how a lot of websites work that you can embed javascript into html. But of course, HTML is markup, not a programming language.

I think to do what you propose would entail writing a new language anyway. Either you would have to create an interpreter/compiler that spoke all of those languages and could frame them consistently, or you would need some way of evaluating line by line explicitly in what would be a meta-language. Those two options are basically the same except for what the programmer has to do to make the languages work together.

Comment: +1 on mixing languages in HTML, but I personally believe it's cleaner to keep the HTML/CSS and JS separated. The web designers can do their thing without trying to wade through stringy JavaScript that's embedded throughout the site.

Comment: You can mix languages in HTML, but not many of them are **programming** languages, which is the topic at hand.

Comment: Eh? Javascript isn't a programming language? PHP? I've also seen perl and python injections although that was with Apache modules.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of combining languages: [Jython](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/whatis.html) (python in Java), [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/) (python used as an embedded code generator in pretty much anything). I've often used Perl code to generate C++, if you count code generation.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework is built for allowing several languages to participate in one solution. It works as long as the language can produce CLR-compatible byte code.

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/1047

Comment: I don't think that's what the original poster meant. The resulting bytecode has very little to do with the way it was written in the language from which it was compiled.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. The author is talking about combining multiple languages in one obscure file.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard, very ugly and often useless to combine multiple programming languages in 1 file.

It is however possible to have a big project written in more than 1 language. For example, both Mozilla Firefox and MySQL have C and C++ code in them. When it comes to big projects, this practice is often used because a particular language provides some features that another does not. In PHP, for example, you can ask for the execution of a binary executable, take its result and use it in your PHP code from that point on.

If you're curious about what languages are used for some of the most important open source projects in the world, you can check out [`Ohloh.net`](http://www.ohloh.net/). Statistics about the source code of many projects can be found there.

Answer (score -1):

Language is a tool. Before choosing a tool (moreover, making some weird hummer-PC-spectroscope combination) one should ask himself - what exactly is it that I want to do?? 
Once the answer is given, you will find out that such kind of languages mixture is seldom necessary.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to mix programming languages so long as your interpreter/compiler can understand it.  For instance mixing javascript, PHP, python in HTML or C++ in C#.

Mixing languages can make it more difficult to read and modify code, however, so it must be done cautiously.  One way around this is to create separate files for code in the language you need to call and to import it rather than embed it.